# Prominence of Scientific Realism and Anti-Realism

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-realism

Just what is the current dominant view on the realism/anti-realism debate on the matter of science? I have read from multiple sources that there is a consistent back-and-forth, but does academic philosophy in America lean in favor of any of these particular views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [philpapers survey](http://philpapers.org/surveys/).

> The PhilPapers Survey was a survey of professional philosophers and others on their philosophical views, carried out in November 2009. The Survey was taken by 3226 respondents, including 1803 philosophy faculty members and/or PhDs and 829 philosophy graduate students.

One question was whether the participants believed in scientific realism or anti-realism. The answer was:

> Accept or lean toward: scientific realism     699 / 931 (75.1%)